# String not working with if else statement

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I'm creating a BMI calculator that works in the English and Metric systems. I'm not really sure what's going on, but no matter what I input it only goes to the first conditional.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




int main()
{
    int weight;
    int height;
    string measurementSystem;

    cout << "Metric or English?: \n";
    cin >> measurementSystem;

    if (measurementSystem == "metric" || "Metric") {

        cout << "Enter your weight (kg): \n";
        cin >>  weight;
        cout << "Enter your height (m): \n";
        cin >> height;

    
    }else if (measurementSystem == "english" ||"English") {

        cout << "Enter your weight (lbs): \n";
        cin >> weight;
        cout << "Enter your height (in): \n";
        cin >> height;
        
    }else{
    
        cout << "Please check spelling";

    }
    


    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: Post code, not images of it

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code text in here. Not a picture of it.

Comment: also `|| "Metric"` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: It should be measurementSystem == "Metric" || measurementSystem == "metric".

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Sorry about that; first day, I did get rid of the image and inserted code instead, thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On lines 17 and 22, you must include the name of the variable in the second clause of the OR operator. E.g.

```
if (measurementSystem == "metric" || measurementSystem == "Metric") {
```

Without this, the bare string `Metric` will evaluate to `true`, because it is non-zero.